# Translating a web page using Array function

Tags: php, arrays, translation

I want to use the array function of PHP to translate a website. I have created PHP files with arrays in them for all the text to be translated.

```
<?php 
//ESPANOL
$lang = array(
              'work' => 'Trabajo'
              'packaging' => 'Empaque'
             );
```

And then I am calling them inside my nav.php file, and will in the content section too.

```
<?php include('includes/languages/es.php'); ?>
<a href="#"><?php echo $lang['work']; ?></a>
```

All pretty straight forward.

What I want to know is how to switch between these array files without editing the HTML, so that I don't have to link to another 'index_es.php' etc. I understand that the link would be something like this, but I don't know how this is going to work.

```
<a href="index.php?es.php>Español</a>|<a href="index.php/?en.php">English</a>
```

I'm guessing I need to include another file that includes the language files and then the link can choose from them but I don't know what the code would be for this. 
Would it involve including a 'lang_directory' above the link and then somehow including from there??

**Also I would like to avoid using Zend/Gettext translation becuase I want to learn this inside out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd keep your array system, correct the links into something like `index.php?lang=en` and then include your file depending on the lang parameter:

```
if ( isset($_GET['lang']) && file_exists('includes/languages/'.$_GET['lang'].'.php') ){
  include_once('includes/languages/'.$_GET['lang'].'.php');
}
```

And if you want to keep the language parameter in your session, do something like this:

```
if ( isset($_GET['lang']) && file_exists('includes/languages/'.$_GET['lang'].'.php') ){
  $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
if ( !isset($_SESSION['lang']) ){
  // Default language
  $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
}
include_once('includes/languages/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php');
```

Comment: So this would be something like using **<?php _the code you put_ ?>** before everything and then changing the links?

Comment: Yes (sorry for the delay!)

Comment: Don't forget session_start() !

Comment: This seems like the most simple and effective. I'll try it and let you know how I get on. Thank you

Comment: When I go between links after changing language it reverts to the ENG lang file. How do I avoid this so it stays in the current language? I'm assuming by adding something in the link php?

Comment: What do your links look like? You need to add the lang parameter only to the links for changing the language, then it should be recorded in the session.

Answer (score 3):

You can make another dimension containing the target language. Then pass a GET parameter to select that language. If the language isn't recognized you can fallback to English. Here's a sample.

```
$languages = array(
    'en' => array(
        'work' => 'work',
        'packaging' => 'packaging'
    ),
    'es' => array(
        'work' => 'Trabajo',
        'packaging' => 'Empaque'
    ),
);

// default language to use when the requested isn't found
$defaultLanguage = 'en';

// language requested via GET
$requested = $_GET['locale'];

// use the requested language if it exists, otherwise the default language
$language = isset($languages[$requested]) ? $requested : $defaultLanguage;

// our translations
$translation = $languages[$language];

// "work" translated based on the language
echo $translation['work'];
```

And the link for Español would look like this.

```
index.php?locale=es
```

Comment: So this is a Multi-Dimensional Array? And I would put all the languages in one file and then include it at the start of the <body> tags as locale.php and the link would run through the array and take use the language it requested?

Comment: Yes this is a multidimensional array, and yes that sounds correct.

Comment: The locale.php would be in the parent directory of index.php then? How does the link work? I mean if I have already included locale.php how does the **?locale=es** change it?

Comment: `locale.php` would be in the same directory as `index.php`. As for `?locale=es`, it's evaluated with `$_GET` and selects the languages array according to what `locale` is equal to.

Comment: How do you handle the full sentence? $translation["work work working a english sentence" ] ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by using sessions.

1. Make a lang.php file that will be used to change between languages.

   ```
   <?php
           //Start session
           session_start();
           //Do we get a lang variable
           if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
                   //Make sure we only get the lang filename
                   $lang = basename($_GET['lang']);
                   //If the file exists, then save it to session
                   if (file_exists('includes/languages/' . $lang . '.php'))
                           $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
           }
           //If the client were refered here (via hyperlink) send them back
           if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
                   header('location: ' + $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
   ?>
   ```
2. In the header of the files you want multiple languages, insert.

   ```
   <?php
           //Start session
           session_start();
           //Default language
           $lang = 'english';
           //If the client have set a language, use that instead
           if (isset($_SESSION['lang']))
                   $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
           //Load language file
           include('includes/languages/' . $lang . '.php');
   ?>
   ```

The links to change language will then be like this:

```
<a href="lang.php?lang=espanol">Español</a>|<a href="lang.php?lang=english">English</a>
```

Out can also take the code from the lang.php file and put in a included file that will be loaded before the inclusion of language file and remove the HTTP_REFERER redirection.

The links to change language will then be like this:

```
<a href="?lang=espanol">Español</a>|<a href="?lang=english">English</a>
```